# How can I start a Mapreduce job when I've disabled datastore writes?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to use the Mapreduce library to do a datastore schema migration on a live App Engine app.

My mapper uses the DatastoreKeyInputReader. Each map operation fetches the old entity using my old schema, does some data manipulation, and then writes the new entity (with a new Kind) under the new schema. I use NDB to get and put the entities transactionally, with the transaction option "force_writes" set to True.

Since the app is live, I want to block all other datastore writes during the migration except for the mapper's transactional writes. Unfortunately, while an individual map operation can run correctly with force_writes set to True in an app with writes disabled, I can't actually start the Mapreduce job - it triggers a CapabilityDisabledError because the Mapreduce library itself doesn't employ force_writes in its own bookkeeping of the jobs.

An obvious hack might be to start the job with writes enabled, and then quickly disable them once the job has started. However, this seems pretty risky to me, especially since my app makes several writes per second under normal conditions. Plus, it would probably break once the job ends unless writes were re-enabled just in time for cleanup.

So, how can I start a Mapreduce job when I need to also disable datastore writes? Seems like the cleanest thing would be for mapreduce.yaml to support a force_writes option for a job...

Answer (score 2):

How long is the mapreduce process going to run for?   If it's not a terribly long process (i.e not 3 days or something) you may want to simply add a default hanlder that routes all traffic to your site to a static HTML maintenance page and then run the mapreduce job.   As soon it's completed you can redeploy with the default handler removed.